# How to export MySql Database to Excell where columns is format as text

Tags: php, mysql, excel

How can I export mysql database to excel, with php, with some columns not formated as general, but as text.

I want for columns SNumber and Phone to be format as text. The id, fname and lname is fine...

My php looks like this:

```
<?php include "db.php"; ?>
<?php ob_start(); ?>
<?php

$output = "";

    if(isset($_POST['export_excel'])) {

        $sql = mysqli_query($connection, "SET NAMES utf8;");
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM table";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

            $output .= "
                <table class='table' bordered='1'>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>FName</th>
                        <th>LName</th>
                        <th>SNumber</th>
                        <th>Phone</th>
                    </tr>
            ";

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

                $output .= "
                    <tr>
                        <td>".$row['id']."</td>
                        <td>".$row['fname']."</td>
                        <td>".$row['lname']."</td>
                        <td>".$row['snumber']."</td>
                        <td>".$row['phone']."</td>
                    </tr>
                ";

                }

                $output .= "</table>";
                header("Content-Type: application/xls");
                header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=kapCMS.xls");

                echo $output;

        }

    }

?>
```

Comment: That's not Excel, that's simply a HTML table. If you want to do magic with Excels column types, you need to build a proper Excel file using PHPExcel or similar where you can set proper types on each column.

Comment: I know that this is not Excel. So, you telling me that I can't do this in here by no means? I have no experience in PHPExcel, is there any tutorial for this?

Comment: HTML doesn't have the concept of data types, since it's just a markup language where types doesn't really matter. Excel is pretty advanced and I doubt that you can do it in plain HTML. Just Google for PHPExcel and try it out.

Comment: You could always spit out a csv and open that in Excel

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values

Comment: @Limiter - That wouldn't help with the data types. If some value is a an integer, Excel will then set is as such instead of text.

Comment: I try to find answer with PHPExcel but I can't find a solution. Is there another way?